# How to make my navigation bar clickable again?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In my website I have a hamburger menu that only shows up when the `width` of the screen is less than 415px. So when you click the hamburger icon it works but when you click like "jobs" or "contact" nothing pops up. There suppose to be a popup div or container that has a x icon on the side and blank div. I've been searching for this for literally 4 hours and can't find anything. Here is my html and the rest will be uploaded to `codepen`.

**`Demo`**: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jBmzRq

`HTML`

```html
<div id="jobs-popup">
  <img id="x-icon1" src="web%20x%20icon%20white.png">
  <div class="jobs-content">
    <a href="mailto:support@magictouchapp.com" target="_top" class="email"></a>
  </div>
</div>
<!--End Section for Jobs Popup -->
    
<!-- Section for contact popup -->
<div id="contact-popup">
  <img id="x-icon2" src="web%20x%20icon%20white.png">
  <div id="contact-content">
    <a href="mailto:support@magictouchapp.com" target="_top" class="email"></a>
    
  </div>
</div>
<!-- End Section for Contact Popup -->
    
<!-- Section for Press popup -->
<div id="press-popup">
  <img id="x-icon3" src="web%20x%20icon%20white.png">
  <div id="press-content">
    <a href="mailto:support@magictouchapp.com" target="_top" class="email"></a>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- End section Press -->
    
<!-- Section for legal popup -->
<div id="legal-popup">
  <img id="x-icon4" src="web%20x%20icon%20white.png">
  <div id="legal-content">
    <a href="mailto:support@magictouchapp.com" target="_top" class="email"></a>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- End section Legal -->
<!-- Section for Support -->
<div id="support-popup">
  <img id="x-icon5" src="web%20x%20icon%20white.png">
  <div id="support-content">
    <a href="mailto:support@magictouchapp.com" target="_top" class="email"></a>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="top-bar">
  <a class="burger-nav"></a>
  <div id="nav-bar">
    <ul>
      <li><a class="nav-list" href="#" id="jobs">Jobs</a></li> 
      <li><a class="nav-list" href="#" id="contact">Contact</a></li>
      <li><a class="nav-list" href="#" id="press">Press</a></li>
      <li><a class="nav-list" href="#" id="legal" id="legal-under">Legal</a></li>
      <li><a class="nav-list" href="#" id="support" id="support-under">Support</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div> 
</div>
<div id="container">
  <div id="background">
  </div>
  <ul id="menu">
  </ul>
  
  <div id="name-div">
    <h1 id="name">Touch</h1>
  </div>
  <ul class="bubbles">
    <li id="firstCircle"></li>
    <li id="secondCircle"></li>
    <li id="thirdCircle"></li>
    <li id="fourthCircle"></li>
    <li id="fifthCircle"></li>
    <li id="sixthCircle"></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I think you have a lot of redundant code there.

Comment: For real? i am just learning and this is how i thought of doing it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to add a drop down menu

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
/* Popup container - can be anything you want */
.popup {
position: relative;
display: inline-block;
cursor: pointer;
-webkit-user-select: none;
-moz-user-select: none;
-ms-user-select: none;
user-select: none;
}

/* The actual popup */
.popup .popuptext {
visibility: hidden;
width: 160px;
background-color: #555;
color: #fff;
text-align: center;
border-radius: 6px;
padding: 8px 0;
position: absolute;
z-index: 1;
bottom: 125%;
left: 50%;
margin-left: -80px;
}

/* Popup arrow */ 
.popup .popuptext::after {
content: "";
position: absolute;
top: 100%;
left: 50%;
margin-left: -5px;
border-width: 5px;
border-style: solid;
border-color: #555 transparent transparent transparent;
}

/* Toggle this class - hide and show the popup */
.popup .show {
visibility: visible;
-webkit-animation: fadeIn 1s;
animation: fadeIn 1s;
}

/* Add animation (fade in the popup) */
@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
from {opacity: 0;} 
to {opacity: 1;}
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
from {opacity: 0;}
to {opacity:1 ;}
}
</style>
</head>
<body style="text-align:center">

<h2>Popup</h2>

<div class="popup" onclick="myFunction()">Click me to toggle the popup!
  <span class="popuptext" id="myPopup">A Simple Popup!</span>
</div>

<script>
// When the user clicks on div, open the popup
function myFunction() {
var popup = document.getElementById("myPopup");
popup.classList.toggle("show");
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The navigation menu wont work because you havent specified a target are a for the a href to go

Comment: in your code it is href="#". create another page such as food.html then replace it with the hashtag.

Comment: No D: its a popup. Its not suppose to open a new page, just a popup.

Comment: And if you are using jquery please include it in the question so that we can see what the problem is

Comment: Where do i put this? can you include it in my code?

Comment: You have many errors in your js and also why are you styling in js

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_popup check this website out. It is example of how easy it is to make a popup box. Your approach is much more sophisticated and also doesnt make sense

Comment: ikr! Idk why i did i that why but do i just copy and paste it and fix it for every media query i do?

Comment: Yes but remember to add this into you head tag                                    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3.css">               otherwise the css from w3 schools wont work